# SQL where clause not returning rows where count equals zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

The goal of this query is to select every workorder template in our database and count each existing workorder where the status isn't closed. I'm utilizing a left join. The left table is the workorder template table. The right table is the workorder table housing every workorder in our db.

```
SELECT      A.DESCRIPTION AS WO_TEMPLATE, COUNT(B.WORKORDERID) AS NUM_OF_WOS
FROM        WOTEMPLATE AS A
LEFT JOIN   WORKORDER AS B
ON          A.WOTEMPLATEID = B.WOTEMPLATEID
WHERE       B.STATUS != 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY    A.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY    WO_TEMPLATE;
```

Our db has a 386 workorder templates...therefore 386 rows should be returned. My issue is when I include the WHERE clause, only 286 rows are returned because workorder templates with no associated workorders aren't being returned.

Given the JOIN, GROUP BY, and WHERE clauses, how do I return rows where the count = 0?

Using Microsoft SQL Server Express

Comment: I just want to complement you on your formatting. Very soothing. Well done. It looks like you took my classes.

Comment: Skip the WHERE clause. Use a case expression to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: I think the only problem is that the `WHERE` clause turns this join into an inner join, because in outer joined rows B.STATUS is null. Change `WHERE` to `AND`. That should be it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That is a great way of visualizing what the WHERE claus does. I may steal that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause turns this join into an inner join, because in outer joined rows B.STATUS is null.

Change `WHERE` to `AND` in order to move the filter on the status column to the join condition for the outer join:

```
SELECT      A.DESCRIPTION AS WO_TEMPLATE, COUNT(B.WORKORDERID) AS NUM_OF_WOS
FROM        WOTEMPLATE AS A
LEFT JOIN   WORKORDER AS B
ON          A.WOTEMPLATEID = B.WOTEMPLATEID
AND         B.STATUS != 'CLOSED'
GROUP BY    A.DESCRIPTION
ORDER BY    WO_TEMPLATE;
```

Comment: So why exactly do you need to both post a comment and an answer? And while your direction might work for this particular case, the general idea is better stated as "move the filter condition from the where clause to the join".

Comment: @SMor: I posted that comment and then I thought that I should better post it as an answer, because then it can be accepted and the answer is apparent for future readers. Then I looked and had a reaction on the comment, so I let it stand. I don't see why wording this as "move the filter condition from the where clause to the join" would be better. Isn't it obvious that this is what's happening by changing `WHERE` to `AND` here? ... Well, maybe you have a point there and someone may overlook this. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thank you for elaborating!